# Suggested edit changing one character only passed through

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, character-limit

There should be such message to user who try to submit suggested edit changing less than 6 characters:

> This edit is less than 6 characters; surely more can be improved with your edit?

However [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2081669) changed "Dynamics" to "Dynamic" and passed through, although it's one single letter.

The bug appears to be in the code comparing the old post to new post: for some reason, the whole word (which is 8 characters) was counted.

Can this be rectified somehow? Those edits are very likely to be too minor.

Comment: This isn't a bug, it's status-bydesign, to my understanding.  It's simply how the diff tool that they use operates.  It's been brought up plenty of times in the past.

Comment: @Servy you mean changing one letter in a word counts the whole word? Didn't find any tag for the diff tool so couldn't really search for similar reports..

Comment: Yes, that's how the diff tool has worked for a very long time, and it's important that it work on whole words rather than partial words.

Comment: Not only was that edit too minor, but it was incorrect. Dynamics CRM WCF is the name of the service as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Servy can you please point me to other post bringing this up? Would gladly close as dupe.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd The most-related post I can find is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132771/smarter-diff-algorithm-for-revision-history).  I remember seeing something more-related, even if it wasn't an exact dupe, but that was a long time ago, so I don't remember enough keywords to find it.

Comment: Another case which may or may not related: http://french.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/2932

Comment: @Gilles yep, looks like when changing a word, the whole word is counted.

Comment: Here's a [recent edit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/52042) which did nothing but remove a comma

Comment: @bobble yeah, and the word next to the comma is six letters, so since it's counted as part of the change, it passed through.