# Text highlighting in revisions is wrong

Tags: bug, revisions-list

For example, when watching revision 2 in [this revisions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/184511/revisions) in the **side-by-side** mode, word "answer" marked as deleted on the left hand side and as added again on the right hand side:

> [image: s-b-s]

If we switch to the **side-by-side markdown** mode no "answer" word is highlighted at all (correctly):

> [image: markdown]

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132771/smarter-diff-algorithm-for-revision-history etc

Comment: @NathanTuggy the first example in the related question already has a valid highligting.

Comment: @NathanTuggy You should add a `bug` tag to your post because it's a bug, not a FR.

Comment: This is fixed now, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291341/115866.