# Insertion highlights in revisions differ between inline vs markdown, and prefer strange similarities

Tags: bug, edits, diff

This seems to be an issue that was [raised in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288006/text-highlighting-in-revisions-is-wrong) and then [marked as status-completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256174/improve-display-of-suggested-edit-deltas-for-format-changes), so I'm not sure if it's a regression or a different issue.

There seems to be a minor issue with the algorithm that tracks and highlights changes in the inline/side-by-side revision history. For example (assuming word boundaries are significant, and ignoring plurals):

[image]

Vs. the markdown view:

[image]

The actual edit made there was the addition of text starting with the word "Furthermore". The markdown view reflects this accurately, but in the formatted view, rather than indicating "version" #1 as unchanged, it instead picked "version" #3.

I have seen this a lot before, as well. The formatted view often differs in highlighting from the markdown view, and appears to prefer the last (or possibly an arbitrary) occurrence of a similarity regardless of the edit, but it seems like it should instead be preferring a similarity that is either closest in proximity to another similarity, or that minimizes the number of disjoint differences, or that coincides with the markdown highlighting.